# MS Chart.NET - how to control Axis Interval in Auto mode?

Tags: intervals, mschart

this probably has been asked before, but I was unable to find a satisfying answer. I am using MS Chart .Net (3.5) control on an ASP.NET page. I'd like to keep AxisX and AxisY in Auto mode - when interval is large and the Axis labels are like "0,5,10,15.." or "0,100,200,300.." it's fine. But when difference between Min and Max values is small - Auto Mode switches to fractions e.g. "0, 0.5, 1, 1.5 .." etc.

My question is: How do I keep interval in Auto mode, but make the minimum "tick" as 1?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as i know if you need to write custom code to do this. eg if (max -min <=5 ( whatever value you decide)) Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Do you know which event I would put this in? Also is there a way at that time to know number of intervals so I can calculate (max - min)/number ?

Comment: You do not need to put this in an event. You can do this after binding your data. You have to decide (max-min).. and interval is 1 so you will know number of intervals.

Comment: The problem is I don't know the max and min every time - it can vary widely

Comment: I understand that.. So after you fill the series with all the datapoints you can easily find maximum and minimum from data points and then decide if you want to set the interval to 1

Comment: Sorry, was being a bit dense this morning. Brilliant solution and works like a charm. Do you mind if I post it at my http://codecorner.galanter.net?

Comment: @Quantbuff Would you mind posting your answer as such?